# editor/IDE which can move css from style atribute to class definition

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know editor/IDE with ability to convert ?

```
.my_class {
    color: black;
}

<span class="my_class" style="font-size: 200%;">test</span>
```

to

```
.my_class {
    color:black;
    font-size: 200%;
}
<span class="my_class" style="">test</span>
```

Why do i need that ? it much faster test/change styles through attribute, especially if there are several external css files.
It's should be integrated in IDE/editor.

Comment: Inline Styling is Bad Practice, its not easier at all, not in the slightest

Comment: Be aware that inline styles have a higher specificity and there is no garauntee that when the styles will apply the same way when they are moved to the style sheet.

Comment: not related to question ( it's used only for quick test/change

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) has a *regular expression* option for search and replace across multiple files. I haven't written any, but I believe you could turn this into a plugin if you wanted to use it frequently.

---

**Remove from inline CSS:**

Find: `(<.*class=".*(my_class).*".*style=".*)(font-size: ?200%;?)(.*">)`

Replace: `\1\4`

**Add to stylesheet:**

Find: `(\.my_class \{\n)((\s*)[^}]*\n)*\}`

Replace: `\1\2\3font-size: 200%;\n\}`

Comment: i think this method not better then move by hand (